# How to upload files or images on hasura graphql engine

Tags: hasura

Example:

- upload file to server and save resulting path to the database, only authenticated users should be able to upload files

How to implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to summarize we have 3 ways:

- client uploads to s3 (or similar service), get's file url, then makes insert/update mutation to the right table
- custom uploader - write application/server that uploads files and mutates db and use nginx routing to redirect some requests to it
- custom resolver using schema stitching ([example](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/5916b97b86fa30c29e35073a923472f84c6782a7/community/boilerplates/custom-resolvers/src/index.js#L27))

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading files to AWS S3, there is a simple way that you don't have to launch another server to process file upload or create a handler for hasura action.

Basically, when you upload files to S3, it's better to get signed url from backend and upload to s3 directly. BTW, for multiple image sizes hosting, [this approach](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) is easy and painless.

The critical point is how to get s3 signed url to upload.
In node.js, you can do

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });
const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  Key: "path/to/file.jpg",
  Expires: 600,
});
console.log("signedUrl", signedUrl);
```

A signedUrl example is like `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKISE362FGWH263SG&Expires=1621134177&Signature=oa%2FeRF36DSfgYwFdC%2BRVrs3sAnGA%3D`.
Normally, you will put the above code to a handler hosted in AWS Lambda or glitch, and add some logic for authorization and even add a row to table.

You can see that the most important part is `Signature=oa%2FeRF36DSfgYwFdC%2BRVrs3sAnGA%3D`. How can we make it easier to get Signature?

After digging into AWS JS SDK, we can find signature is computed [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/307e82673b48577fce4389e4ce03f95064e8fe0d/lib/util.js#L428).

```js
return util.crypto.lib.createHmac(fn, key).update(string).digest(digest);

fn = 'sha1'
string = 'PUT\n\n\n1621135558\b/my-bucket/path/to/file.jpg'
digest = 'base64'
```

It's just sha1 a certain format of string. This means we can just use hasura computed fields and Postgres crypto function to achieve the same results.

So if you have a table "files"

```sql
CREATE TABLE files (
   id SERIAL,
   created_at timestamps,
   filename text,
   user_id integer
);
```

you can create a SQL function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.file_signed_url(file_row files)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
  SELECT ENCODE( HMAC(
  
  'PUT' ||E'\n'||E'\n'||E'\n'|| 
  (cast(extract(epoch from file_row.created_at) as integer) + 600)
  ||E'\n'|| '/my-bucket/' || file_row.filename
  
  , 'AWS_SECRET', 'SHA1'), 'BASE64')
$function$
```

Finally, follow [this](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/computed-fields.html) to expose this computed field to Hasura.

This way allows you to be able to not add any backend stuff and handle permission all in Hasura.

Comment: While this looks appealing, this signature is the v2 one, which has been deprecated since 2018. The current v4 signature is significantly harder to compute in SQL.